# Is it possible to enable Adobe Flash in Edge on the Creators Edition of Windows 10?

Tags: microsoft-edge, adobe-flash, windows-10-v1703

If I try to visit a webpage that uses Adobe Flash (such as [this MSN news story, linked from the Edge start page](http://www.msn.com/en-gb/news/world/us-drops-mother-of-all-bombs-on-is-held-caves-in-afghanistan/ar-BBzOwho?li=AAmiR2Z&ocid=spartanntp)) it loads, then reloads twice before showing:

> ### This page is having a problem loading
>
> We tried to load this page for you a few times, but there is still a problem with this site. We know you have better things to do than to watch this page reload over and over again so try coming back to this page later.

I want to rule out the new feature of having disable Adobe Flash by default, so can this be re-enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Flash can be enabled by hitting the three dots to the right of the address bar, choosing Settings, select View Advanced Settings, and there is an option there to enable Adobe Flash